# Keras - Linear stack of layers?

Tags: neural-network, keras

I started to follow this "guide" to learn how to make a neural network but I'm already stuck at the first sentence

https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/

What the hell is a LINEAR stack of layer ?

Does it mean the derivative of the stack is a constant ? (kidding but I'm getting really frustrated by guides who don't define what they're saying)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A linear stack is a model without any branching. Every layer has one input and output. The output of one layer is the input of the layer below it.

Stacks which are not linear can have layers with multiple inputs and outputs. They can have complex connections between layers

Comment: How does it look like? Is it like a fully connected feed-forward network?

Comment: Yes.  In comparison a network using recurrency or residual connections would not be a linear stack.

Answer (score 0):

The term linear stack is used to mean that there is no funny business going on, e.g. recurrency (connections can go backwards) or residual connections (connections can skip layers).  The connections between neurons go from one layer to the next, no more, no less.

Fully connected feed-forward layers are an example of a linear stack.